# How to judge (but not test) which monitors are good for sub-pixel rendering when turned on side?

Tags: display

I am planning on adding a second monitor, 1680*1050 but turning it on its side to show more lines of code. I am concerned about subpixel rendering, especially since the reason of buying the monitor in the first place is to display text. Unfortunately, it is impractical to drag my desktop into every store and try to convince the salespeople to let me test different configurations on each monitor. How might I select a good monitor for this purpose considering that I won't be able to test it and that most monitors are meant to be shiny and show movies, not matte and show text.

I'm running Kubuntu with FOSS drivers, and using the onboard video of a recent Asus motherboard, if that matters.

Comment: No access to my KDE box right now, but isn't there an option in the fonts dialog that lets you change the subpixel rendering from RGB-horizontal to RGB-vertical (along with other configs)? I think that's what I did when I flipped my second monitor into portrait.

Comment: Yes, the setting exists. But monitor subpixels are not necessarily linearly spaced, and monitor engineers might not have taken into account that some viewing angles will be above the 'height' of the monitor (to the left if the monitor is rotated counterclockwise). There are other considerations as well, such as the fact that most LCD pixels are far from square.